# Static Graphviz libraries for iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, static-libraries, graphviz, configure

I've been trying to build static armv7 and i386 Graphviz libraries for iOS. I've followed just about every tutorial and finally managed to build both libraries. I copy every i386 *.a library file into a folder in Xcode. I do the same with every *.a armv7 file and every *.h header file. My problem is that Xcode is throwing symbol not found errors. Any ideas as to why the symbols are not found?

```
Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:
  "_drawGraph", referenced from:
      -[FNETGraph render] in FNETGraph.o
  "_createGraph", referenced from:
      -[FNETGraph render] in FNETGraph.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Here is my configure and make code for armv7:

```
export DEV_iOS=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer
export SDK_iOS=${DEV_iOS}/SDKs/iPhoneOS6.1.sdk
export COMPILER_iOS=${DEV_iOS}/usr/bin

export CC=${COMPILER_iOS}/gcc
export CPP=${COMPILER_iOS}/llvm-cpp-4.2
export CXX=${COMPILER_iOS}/g++
export CXXCPP=${COMPILER_iOS}/g++
export OBJC=${COMPILER_iOS}/gcc
export LD=${COMPILER_iOS}/ld

export LDFLAGS="-arch armv7 -isysroot ${SDK_iOS}"
export CFLAGS="${LDFLAGS} -miphoneos-version-min=6.1"
export CXXFLAGS="${LDFLAGS} -miphoneos-version-min=6.1 -fvisibility-inlines-hidden"
export CXXCPPFLAGS="${LDFLAGS} -miphoneos-version-min=6.1"
export OBJCFLAGS="${LDFLAGS} -miphoneos-version-min=6.1 -fvisibility-inlines-hidden"

export AR=${COMPILER_iOS}/ar
export AS=${COMPILER_iOS}/as
export NM=${COMPILER_iOS}/nm
export CXXCPP=${COMPILER_iOS}/llvm-cpp-4.2
export RANLIB=${COMPILER_iOS}/ranlib

./configure --host=arm-apple-darwin11 
            --disable-dependency-tracking 
            --enable-shared=no 
            --enable-static=yes 
            --enable-ltdl-install=no 
            --enable-ltdl=no 
            --enable-swig=no 
            --enable-tcl=no 
            --with-codegens=no 
            --with-fontconfig=no 
            --with-freetype2=no 
            --with-ipsepcola=yes 
            --with-libgd=no 
            --with-quartz=yes 
            --with-visio=yes 
            --with-x=no 
            --with-cgraph=yes

make
touch lib/gvpr/gdefs.h
make

mkdir -p ~/Desktop/Graphiz/armv7
find . -name '*.a' -execdir cp '{}' ~/Desktop/Graphiz/armv7 \;

mkdir -p ~/Desktop/Graphiz/headers
find . -name '*.h' -execdir cp '{}' ~/Desktop/Graphiz/headers \;
```